# How to authorize actions with the [Authorize(Roles)] attribute?

Tags: asp.net-identity, postman, asp.net-core-webapi

I am trying to create a simple Web API with a controller based on a single model class.

I've added `AddIdentity` in the `Startup.cs`, created two user roles and tried to authorize an action in the controller so that it can be specifically accessed by one of the two roles. However, no matter what I try to use to test it, it always results in an error where the response states that the server doesn't even enter the the specified action. So far I tried using Postman and Swagger UI, neither of which provided me with a proper response.

The action that I am trying to access would be this one:

```cs
        // GET api/media
        [HttpGet]
        [Authorize(Roles = "Member")]
        public IEnumerable<Media> Get()
        {
            return _mediaData.Get();
        }
```

Here's how I added Identity support in the `Startup.cs` class:

```
services.AddIdentity<User, Role>(config => { config.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = false; })
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
                //.AddDefaultUI()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

What I expected was a JSON object, but as a results Swagger provides me with an error which states that it was expected for me to login, but I am not sure how I can do that. I suppose I need to learn more stuff regarding the SignIn and UserManager, but I have no idea how I would "login and open a session" (that's what I assume would solve the problem) and I've been unable to find any resource explaining how to do it, much less how get the result via Postman or Swagger UI.

Comment: Are you trying to implement a web application that will use your Web API or just an API for 3rd-party consumers?

Comment: @SergeyKhutornoy I am trying to implement a web api that will be used by a web application (MVC) and perhaps a WinForms app (using an Http client like Flurl).

Comment: Have you created the user and assign the role to the user? Before calling a secured method, you need to login. Have you processed the login before the request?

Comment: @TaoZhou After checking the stuff a bit deeper, yes, turns out I am not logged in even though I tried passing the username and password via both Swagger UI and Postman. Unfortunately, I can't think of another way to "login to the api".

Comment: What do you mean it did not login?

Comment: Even though I state the username and password in the authorization info (Swagger UI, for example), it still returns me with an error where it expected me "to login first".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Swagger UI provides an authentication method for you, for which you need to make a few changes to your `Startup.cs`. For that, modify your `ConfigureServices` method to something like:

```cs
services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
    c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info { Title = "My API", Version = "v1" });
    c.AddSecurityDefinition("basic", new BasicAuthScheme() { Type = "basic" }); // Depending on your authentication, this will look different, but the most common one would be the Basic Authentication, so perhaps play with that or go with what you already had in mind
    c.DocumentFilter<BasicAuthDocumentFilter>();
});
```

If you go with the Basic Authentication, you can use the code below to provide Swagger with the document filter (`BasicAuthDocumentFilter`), which may look like:

```cs
public class BasicAuthDocumentFilter : IDocumentFilter
{
    public void Apply(SwaggerDocument swaggerDoc, DocumentFilterContext context)
    {
        var securityRequirements = new Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>>()
        {
            { "basic", new string[] { } }
        };
        swaggerDoc.Security = new[] { securityRequirements };
    }
}
```

To use it, simply open Swagger UI and you should see an Authorize button just below the title. Click on it and provide the necessary authentication info it requires and you should be good to go.

As for ASP Identity, it's not very common to use ASP Identity for Web APIs if I am not mistaken. I would personally switch over to Basic or OAITH since those sound more natural when talking about APIs.