ASP.NET Core Model Binding Issue: [FromBody] Parameter Always Null in POST Request
I'm working on an ASP.NET Core Web API endpoint where I need to accept a JSON object from a POST request body. However, the parameter is consistently null, even when sending a properly structured request from Swagger.
Here's what I have - my controller:
[ApiController]
[Route("/api/user/[controller]/[action]")]
[Authorize(Roles = ServiceConstants.AuthenticationRoleUser)]
public class DamavandController : BaseController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult<DamavandTransactionResult>> RequestTransactions([FromBody] GetTransactionModel transactionModel)
    {
        if (transactionModel == null)
        {
            _logger.LogError("Model binding failed: transactionModel is null.");
            return BadRequest("Model binding failed: transactionModel is null.");
        }

        var transactions = await GetDamavandComponent().GetTransactions(transactionModel.DateFrom, transactionModel.DateTo, transactionModel.TerminalNumber, transactionModel.Limit, transactionModel.Offset);

        return Ok(transactions);
    }
}

namespace DecaPay.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Produces("application/json")]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
    public class BaseController : ControllerBase
    {
    }
}

My model class:
public class GetTransactionModel
{
    public string DateFrom { get; set; }
    public string DateTo { get; set; }
    public long TerminalNumber { get; set; }
    public int Limit { get; set; } = 25;
    public int Offset { get; set; } = 0;
}

This is the JSON I am posting:
{
  "DateFrom": "2024/08/19",
  "DateTo": "2024/08/20",
  "TerminalNumber": 123456,
  "Limit": 25,
  "Offset": 0
}

What I've tried:

Added [ApiController] to enable automatic model binding and validation

Confirmed that the JSON payload structure in Swagger matches the GetTransactionModel property names

Set default values for Limit and Offset

Verified that Content-Type is application/json in Swagger



have you tried to check without the [Authorize] ?

Try adding the [Consumes("application/json")] attribute to your controller class:
namespace DecaPay.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Consumes("application/json")]
    [Produces("application/json")]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
    public class BaseController : ControllerBase
    {

    }
}


Your api endpoint has an authorize attribute. See if this link helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56120785/how-to-authorize-actions-with-the-authorizeroles-attribute
